# How to flow text in 2 columns with custom style?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm writing a website with HTML, CSS and jQuery. I have a text that has a 2-column style and a picture before the text like this:

```
   <div>
      <div style="float:right">
          <img src="imageSource"/>
      </div>    
      <div style="-webkit-column-count: 2; -moz-column-count: 2; column-count: 2;">
          TEXT
      </div>
   </div>
```

I want the first column to appear before the image and the second column to be under the picture, like this:

[image]

how can I do this?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/vx5wkybt/1/

Answer (score 0):

## [DEMO:](http://jsfiddle.net/vx5wkybt/)

Try this:

```
img{float:right;
    width:150px; 
    height:150px;
    background:#333;
    margin:10px;
}

div {
       -moz-column-count: 2;
       -moz-column-gap: 20px;
       -webkit-column-count: 2;
       -webkit-column-gap: 20px;
}
```