# Inserting Picture into a 2-column text

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm writing a website with HTML, CSS and jQuery. I have a text that has a 2-column style and a picture before the text like this:

```
   <div>
      <div style="float:right">
          <img src="imageSource"/>
      </div>    
      <div style="-webkit-column-count: 2; -moz-column-count: 2; column-count: 2;">
          TEXT
      </div>
   </div>
```

I want the first column to appear before the image and the second column to be under the picture, like this:

[image]

how can I do this?

Comment: Easier: http://jsfiddle.net/y8md61no/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25711241/how-to-flow-text-in-2-columns-with-custom-style

Comment: No, I cannot break the text. The text is generated automatically

Comment: aah, then wait a minute

Comment: closed this as a duplicate. Just edit your original question and add the code there.

Comment: In your image the text is braked in 2 columns

Answer (score 0):

Make it like this:

```
<div class="col1">text</div>
<div class="col2">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/200x100">
    <div class="col2text">text</div>
</div>
```

And the CSS:

```
.col1{
    float:left;
    width:200px;
    border:1px solid black;
    height:400px;
}
.col2{
    width:200px;
    border:1px solid red;
    height:400px;
    float:left;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/y8md61no/